# Artwork from different designers: Achieving an integrated look?

Tags: website-design

First of all, I am not a graphic designer.

I am launching a new website soon. I have the text almost ready. I have a web designer and infographic designer.

In order to prevent visitors meeting walls of text. I am now thinking livening up text by adding stock vector-line art  from sites like https://www.flaticon.com/. I can submit these to the webdesigner. However, I will also be submitting infographics from another specialist infographic designer.

Using this approach, is it possible to achieve an integrated look or is it going to look messy? I would really appreciate your opinion on this.

Comment: I don't think this is a real question. It all comes down to using good design sense when selecting web elements.

Comment: As @Westide points out, any decent designer should be able to match a given style. So pick the style you want and communicate that to the designers (just send them a link to the flat icons you intend to use). Or pick one of your designers and determine their work will be the basis for other work.

Answer (score 4):

The key with a project like this is that something needs to lead the design style. Either you need to get the web designer to follow the style of the infographics or vice versa. If you are using stock vectors then both of your designers will need to match the style of whatever they create to the stock content or alter the stock vectors to fit with the master style. Allowing different designers to work independently without an overarching style guide or creative brief is only ever going to result in a disjointed and inconsistent end product.

Comment: Thanks. So I'll create a master style sheet. But, apart for colour matching, what other elements of style should look consistent. Again, I am not a designer. I just want to de-construct exactly what constitutes "a consistent look" in my head.

Comment: For a professional, uniform appearance, everything should be consistent; fonts, text size, line spacing colours, line weights, borders, etc. As you said, you’re not a designer, so let one of your designers define the style, to your brief. Giving too specific a brief can be like making a designer work one handed.